# Using Laravel Socialite as an API (Social Authentication)

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework, jwt, laravel-socialite

I want to use #Laravel_Socialite as an #API for my #ionic app, but sever error keeps displaying.
Can anyone know the issue? Im sure the ionic function has something wrong as Im posting nothing in the request
Please help.

Laravel Functions:

```
public function redirectToFacebook()
    {
        $url = Socialite::with('facebook')->stateless()->redirect()->getTargetUrl();
        return \response()->json([
            'url' => $url
        ], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handleFacebookCallback()
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::with('facebook')->stateless()->user();;
            $create['name'] = $user->getName();
            $create['email'] = $user->getEmail();
            $create['facebook_id'] = $user->getId();
            

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return \response()->json([
                'code' => $e->getCode(),
                'message' => 'error'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Laravel Routes:
[image]

Login.ts function (ionic) :

```
fbLogin()
{
  this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 'connected') {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        console.log("detailsss");
        this.getUserDetail(res.authResponse.userID);
        this.authService.handleFacebookCallback().subscribe(
          res => { 
            console.log("accesstooooken2")
            console.log(res);
            }, err => {
                 console.log(err);
            });
        console.log("res");
        console.log(res);
        this.route.navigate(['/home']);
      } else {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    }),  (error: any) => {
      console.log(error);  
    }}
```

Service function:

[image]

Comment: A server error typically comes with some sort of details of *what* that error is; it may be in your logs.

Comment: @ceejayoz is the flow right? What should I send from ionic to api?